# Allow different headers on different servers using WFF

Tags: iis

We've got multiple web servers configured in a cluster using Microsoft's Web Farm Framework. One of the things I like to do to help debugging is to create a header in IIS that identifies the server that handled the request. Unfortunately when I try to do this, WFF sets the headers to the same value on all the servers. Is there a way around this?

I tried looking into using skipDirectives, but I can't find any documentation on it (other than a little bit showing how to use it to skip directories and bindings).

If there is documentation on this, please link to it! I would like to be able to read up more on it in case I need to do other things as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian,

An example of how you can accomplish this is by creating an response header on the primary web server node using URL Rewrite that adds a new header with `{SERVER_ADDR}` server variable.  Using a server variable allows you to make the rule as generic as possible so that you don't need to have WFF skip any sections of config files.

The web.config entry for this type of response header would be:

```
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="Add Server Node to Response">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Node" pattern="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{SERVER_ADDR}" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
```

This rule will put the web server's IP address in a response header called `Node`.  This can lead to some information disclose that you may not with to disclose.  Because of this, you can also use a rewrite map to map your different server IP's to a name that uniquely identifies them, like 'Node1'.

You can find more information on setting response headers at http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/modifying-http-response-headers.

### Edit:

To perform the mapping of the `SERVER_ADDR` server variable to a name you provide, you would do the following in your web.config...

```
    <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="Add Server Node to Response">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Node" pattern="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{NodeMappings:{SERVER_ADDR}}" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="NodeMappings">
                <add key="10.0.0.1" value="Node1" />
                <add key="10.0.0.2" value="Node2" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>
```

Keep in mind, this would require you to update this section every time a node IP changes or a node is added to the farm.

Comment: Thanks! You hinted at adding custom server variables with unique values for each server. The article that you linked didn't seem to include information on doing that. I did find some suggestions using Google, but it required code in an http handler. Do you know of a way of creating these server variables without code?

Comment: @Brian, I'm glad you asked...it has forced me to look into how to actually do this (it was just a theory as I wrote it before).  This would actually not require any kind of custom server variable, I misled you on that.  What you will need is a rewrite map that maps the different server IPs to a name you assign to it.  You would then change `{SERVER_ADDR}` to `{Nodes:{SERVER_ADDR}}` where `Nodes` is the name you assign to the rewrite map.  This will take the `SERVER_ADDR` variable and map it to the names you configured in your rewrite map.  I'll update the above answer to include this info.

Comment: Unfortunately SERVER_ADDR just gives me the IP of the cluster (Windows NLB), not the individual machine. Any more ideas?